# Using a function in a WHERE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using a function to split a comma delimited parameter into a table to filter results in a stored procedure.

Will the following function (SplitStrList2Table) be invoked for every row if it is placed in the WHERE condition?

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM result_after
WHERE result_after.DepartmentId IN 
(SELECT item FROM [dbo].[SplitStrList2Table](@DepartmentIds))
```

Would using a temporary table make a difference?

Function SQL:

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrList2Table]
(@List varchar(MAX))
RETURNS 
@ParsedList table (item int)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @item varchar(800), @Pos int

SET @List = LTRIM(RTRIM(@List))+ ','
SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @List, 1)

WHILE @Pos > 0
BEGIN
    SET @item = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@List, @Pos - 1)))
    IF @item <> ''
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @ParsedList (item) 
        VALUES (CAST(@item AS int))
    END
    SET @List = RIGHT(@List, LEN(@List) - @Pos)
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @List, 1)
END

RETURN
```

Comment: Why not use CROSS APPLY or a join?

Comment: Short answer: no on the first question. That's not a row level function, which would be in the `SELECT` portion of the statement. For the second question on the temp table - what is stopping you from trying it? Also - what does this have to do with `entity-framework` as tagged?

Comment: I am guessing the reason for your question is performance. If that split function has a loop, cursor, recursive cte or more than a single statement the function is likely the cause of the performance problem.

Comment: So the `SELECT item FROM [dbo].[SplitStrList2Table](@DepartmentIds)` part of the query is only executed once?

Comment: It depends. If it is a multi statement TVF it will only be executed once and the plan will have a sequence operator filling the table then using it. If it is an inline TVF it could be executed multiple times (if on the inner side of a nested loops and no spool)

Comment: The others have eluded to it, but to give an answer to the question, you need to supply the code for `SplitStrList2Table`. Without knowing what the SQL behind that statement is, we can't answer definitively; but just give different examples and what would happen for those.

Comment: @MichaelO'Neill, I did try it but can't tell the difference, I realized the scalability issue today.

Comment: @SeanLange, currently there is nothing wrong with it, even after changing to a temp table I see no difference. I just want to know.

Comment: And we have a winner....the performance issue is that splitter code. You should throw it in the trash. Unless you are on 2016 you need a better splitter. My personal choice can be found here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ There are many other great alternatives here. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: @Larnu edited the question

Comment: @SeanLange interesting articles, thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, this is using a `WHILE` loop, which means it's a Multi-statement TVF. personally, I'd considering looking for an alternate solution which uses an inline TVF. @SeanLange 's second link has several good options for you to consider. The first link does, also, link to the one I personally use. Many don't like it because it's limited to a `varchar(8000)`/`nvarchar(4000)`, however, if you're dealing with a delimtied string longer than that in your data, then (personally I feel) the problem isn't the splitter, it's the fact you have a huge delimited list in your data.

Comment: @Larnu the first link is also a good solution for splitting. It is an inline table valued function that is crazy fast. It has some limitations that some of the other don't. But it returns the position of the item which most other splitters (and even MS) don't. ;)

Comment: @SeanLange I was already editing my comment. Hadn't noticed (initially) that the first link was to the `delimitedSplit8K`.

Comment: The OP has stated that they don't have a performance issue so you are solving a problem that doesn't currently exist.

Comment: @MartinSmith oh please....they think they don't have a performance issue. That splitter is a performance black hole. We have all seen it many times.

Comment: @MartinSmith not so sure they aren't. Their main question is appears to be "Would using a temporary table make a difference?". This is a pretty clear indication, in my view, that they're looking for alternatives, most likely to make their query perform better.

Comment: @Larnu they say above "currently there is nothing wrong with it". Potentially there better ways of splitting a string but they haven't indicated that they are unhappy with the current performance. If they are just sending relatively short strings given that the splitting code is only executed once replacing with a different splitter will have negligible effect.

Comment: @MartinSmith "nothing wrong" and "performs badly" aren't synonymous. We can all write code that has nothing wrong with it; doesn't mean it's good code. Much like writing Dynamic SQL that is wide open to SQL injection ash "nothing wrong" with it. It's a disaster waiting to happen, but it performs to job that was intended.

Comment: @Larnu if it performs badly then there wouldn't be nothing wrong. The two statements are contradictory.

Comment: I think you've completely missed my point.

Comment: @Larnu the issue is my lack of knowledge, not performance. I quickly tested it and found no indication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the following function (SplitStrList2Table) be invoked for every row if it is placed in the WHERE condition?

No. It is a multistatement TVF. The plan will have a sequence operator where it first calls the function and populates the table variable and then uses it in the rest of the plan.

This isn't necessarily ideal though. Even though it is only called once your splitter code is not very optimal, additionally you do not declare any indexes on the table variable that might help. Also at the moment there will be a fixed estimate for the number of rows returned by the TVF (unless on a version supporting [interleaved execution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2017/04/19/introducing-interleaved-execution-for-multi-statement-table-valued-functions/) where the plan can be recompiled after the table variable population step.)